# build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'

Tags: python, django, paypal

I am using django framework and trying to integrate a paypal payment gateway. But I am getting this error

```
build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
```

Django Version: 1.11.11
Python Version: 3.6.3
Exception Value: build_attrs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'
Exception Location: /home/iuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paypal/standard/widgets.py in render, line 35

```
from django import forms
try:
    from django.forms.utils import flatatt # Django 1.7 and later
except ImportError:
    from django.forms.util import flatatt # earlier

from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.encoding import force_text


class ValueHiddenInput(forms.HiddenInput):
    """
    Widget that renders only if it has a value.
    Used to remove unused fields from PayPal buttons.
    """

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            return u''
        else:
            return super(ValueHiddenInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)


class ReservedValueHiddenInput(ValueHiddenInput):
    """
    Overrides the default name attribute of the form.
    Used for the PayPal `return` field.
    """

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type)
        if value != '':
            final_attrs['value'] = force_text(value)
        return mark_safe(u'<input%s />' % flatatt(final_attrs))
```

Comment: The signature has changed: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28095

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11) the `build_attrs` function has been changed as specified in the [release notes [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#miscellaneous):

> The signature of private API `Widget.build_attrs()` **changed from `extra_attrs=None, **kwargs` to `base_attrs, extra_attrs=None`**.

You need to change the call to:

```
class ReservedValueHiddenInput(ValueHiddenInput):
    """
    Overrides the default name attribute of the form.
    Used for the PayPal `return` field.
    """

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, {'type': self.input_type})
        if value != '':
            final_attrs['value'] = force_text(value)
        return mark_safe(u'<input%s />' % flatatt(final_attrs))
```

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much you brighten my day. It works.